# Cannot create a list from request.body in Django 1.8 using json.loads()

Tags: python, json, django

for example, i send via js this json string

```
{data: "[{"id":1},{"id":2}]"}
```

and on server side i try to create a dict from it:

```
result = json.loads(str(request.body, 'utf-8'))
print(result)                     # {'data': '[{"id":1},{"id":2}]'}
print(type(result['data']))       # <class 'str'> (not list!!!)
print(str(request.body, 'utf-8')) # {"data":"[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2}]"}
```

so, why json.loads doesn't create a list? I use python 3

Answer (score 3):

Because you've got quotes in data

```
{'data': "[I'M STRING]"}

{'data': [im_list]}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, anti1869

Finally, i got why it didn't work. I had a form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="datafield" type="hidden" name="data" value="[{"id":1},{"id":2}]"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and submitted it like this (wrong, it apends quotes to the brackets):

```
$.ajax({ 
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify( $('form').serializeArray() ), // sends with double quotes near brackets
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Now i dont use this form at all:

```
        var j = [{"id":1},{"id":2}];
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(j),   // sends normally
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
```

Comment: my mistake, in first case i stringify already stringified array)